# Subtraction of LOADADDR doesn't work in output section

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, riscv

I'm trying to define a symbol to specify the rom size in the linker script.

Method 1: The expression of LOADADDR subtraction as below doesn't work.

```
.text : ALIGN(0x10)
{
  ...
  __etext = .;
} > ROM

.gmac_hash : AT(__etext + SIZEOF(.sdata) + SIZEOF(.data)) ALIGN(0x4)
{
  __rom_size = LOADADDR(.gmac_hash) - LOADADDR(.text);
  ...
} > ROM
```

Method2: Then I separated two LOADADDR expression and fixed the issue.

```
.text : ALIGN(0x10)
{
  ...
  __etext = .;
} > ROM

.gmac_hash : AT(__etext + SIZEOF(.sdata) + SIZEOF(.data)) ALIGN(0x4)
{
  __text_load_start = LOADADDR(.text);
  __rom_size = LOADADDR(.gmac_hash) - __text_load_start;
  ...
} > ROM
```

Method 3: Move the subtraction outside of the output section also works well.

```
.text : ALIGN(0x10)
{
  ...
  __etext = .;
} > ROM

.gmac_hash : AT(__etext + SIZEOF(.sdata) + SIZEOF(.data)) ALIGN(0x4)
{
  ...
} > ROM
__rom_size = LOADADDR(.gmac_hash) - LOADADDR(.text);
```

I cannot figure out why the first method doesn't work. And here's my GCC version

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -dumpversion
7.2.0
```

Could anyone explain why method 1 doesn't work?

Comment: I have the same problem in gcc 10.  I get the same value whether I use subtraction or addition!